# Hidden speech bubble toolltip for image

Tags: html, css, image, tooltip

I have this code where the hidden speech bubble appears when you hover over an image.

http://jsfiddle.net/e4q7K/19/

```
  #container {
background-color: #FF0;
margin: 100px;
float: left;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
 }

  div.hoverbubble {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  }

 div.hoverbubble span {display: none;}
 div.hoverbubble:hover span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding: .5em;
content: attr(title);
min-width: px;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
height: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
top: -40px;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 0.86em;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   }
  div.hoverbubble:hover span:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
content: "";
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) transparent transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
bottom: -20px;
left: 1em;
   }

  <div id="container"><div class="hoverbubble"><img src="test.gif" width="50"  
   height="50" border="0" /><span>Hidden message here.</span></div>
```

And i was wondering if there is a way to style the image to this?

```
  width:100%; border:1px solid {color:border}; margin-bottom:6px;
 {block:ifroundedsidepic}
 -webkit-border-radius:100px; -moz-border-radius:100px; border-radius:100px; 
 {/block:ifroundedsidepic}
```

I've tried doing this:

```
 <img src="{image:sidepic}" style="width:100%; border:1px solid {color:border}; margin-
 bottom:6px;{block:ifroundedsidepic}-webkit-border-radius:100px; -moz-border-
 radius:100px; border-radius:100px;{/block:ifroundedsidepic}"/>
```

And I've also tried creating an image id, "#kuroko" in the CSS and changed the html to

```
<img id="kuroko"  src="{image:sidepic}" /><span>Hidden message here.</span>
```

But it did not work. Is there any possible way to style this image?

Answer (score 0):

To style an element right after another one, you need to use the selector : **`+`**.
Your case will be :

```
<img/><span></span>
```

with the css base :

```
img + span {
display:none;
}
img:hover + span {
display:block;
}
```

For the case of using the attribute `title` and a pseudo element from `img` , it will not be possible. `img` and input, for instance,  can not generate pseudo elements.